# model.matrix doesn't work for dataframe with multiple rows

Tags: r, rbind

I have a very simple data frame that I wish to turn into a matrix.

```
df <- data.frame(age=c(50, 60), sex=factor(c('M', 'F')))
```

However, when I try to run `model.matrix` it fails:

```
model.matrix(1 ~ age + sex, df)

Error in model.frame.default(object, data, xlev = xlev) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'age')
```

However, if I run a row at a time it's fine.

```
model.matrix(1 ~ age + sex, df[1, ])

 (Intercept) age sexM
1           1  50    1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 2
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$sex
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

I've got what I want working with an `lapply` over the rows and `do.call('rbind', ...)` to join it back together, but I must be missing something right?

Comment: The `1` is your problem. You can use `model.matrix(~ age + sex, df)` if you don't want to specify a response.

Comment: Ah so simple. Brilliant if you put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `1` is your problem because it is length 1. You can use `model.matrix(~ age + sex, df)` if you don't want to specify a response.